# XML schema for restricting child node

Tags: xsd

I need to create xml schema where all the nodes `<foo>` must contain either one or more occurance of `<c1>` only or one occurance of `<c2>` only as follows.

```
 <main>
  <foo>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c1></c1>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c1></c1>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c1></c1>
  </foo>
</main>
```

or

```
<main>
  <foo>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c2></c2>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c2></c2>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c2></c2>
  </foo>
</main>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you have an "either - or" situation, your solution is usually `<xs:choice>`. Use `maxOccurs` and `minOccurs` attributes to restrict how many times element can appear. Default value for those attributes is "1" which is used if you don't add those attributes.

A sample code snippet for the definition of the `<foo>` element. Note the usage of `<xs:choice>` and `maxOccurs="unbounded"`

```
<xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string />
            <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string />
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="c1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string />
                <xs:element name="c2" type="xs:string />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```